# ajax response to displaying results in given id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a javascript onchange function on my select tag which when selected it sends the data to my php file and retruns it. i want the results to be displayed in a textbox with ID typid. all seems well. the function response returns data from the php file but for some reason its not displaying in my textbox. i tried to display in a span tag but still not working. kindly help. below is my function.

```
 function getvalues(){
    var select1 =document.getElementById('select1').value;

    var datastring = 'select1='+select1;

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"gettypid.php",
        data:datastring,
        dataType: 'Text',
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){
             var k= html;
             //$("#typid").html(html.responseText);  
            // alert(k);
            $('#typid').HTML(html);
        getvalues();
        }

    });
    return false;

}
```

Comment: For textbox you need to use .val() not .html() use `$("#typid").val(html)`

Comment: also it is $('#typid').html(html); and not "HTML"

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.val()` function to set value.

```
$('#typid').val(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Form inputs have no html values so if you want to get or set the input text by using val() function.**

```
function getvalues(){
    var select1 = document.getElementById('select1').value;

    var datastring = 'select1='+select1;

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"gettypid.php",
        data:datastring,
        dataType: 'Text',
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){
            $('#typid').val(html);
            getvalues();
        }

    });
    return false;

}
```